# How to code a interleaved Generic Factory class in java

Tags: java, generics, factory

Suppose we have an interface
`public interface Doll {}` 
and a Class that implements it:

```
public class BaseDoll implements Doll {
    //Implementation of class;
    public BaseDoll(String data) {
        //construct class based on that string.
    }
}
```

Now assume we have a generic class

```
public class ExtDoll<T extends Doll> implements Doll {
    T data;

    public ExtDoll(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

My goal is to instantiate objects in the form of `ExtDoll<... <ExtDoll<BaseDoll>...>`.  I think a good approach is a factory class

```
public class DollFactory<T extends Doll> {
    public T getInstance(String data) {
        //what to write here?
    }
}
```

with the call

```
DollFactory<ExtDoll<ExtDoll<BaseDoll>>> df = new DollFactory<>();
ExtDoll<ExtDoll<BaseDoll>> d = df.getInstance("string that describes the obj");
```

The idea behind this codesnippet is some sort of Matrjoschka. In my real program I have different classes that implements Doll, hence the generic approach. I thought that I might be able to solve it recursively:

```
   public T getInstance(String data) {
    //1:Use reflection to get the type of the layer below
    //2:Create a DollFactory element with the type of the layer below <-- is that even possible?
    //3: adapt the string and create the object of the lower layer with that new Factory
    //4: create the final object
}
```

but I am not sure how to create the factory in step 2), since I can't extract the Identifier from the class object and I guess that this is not possible in Java (which makes sense). Do you have different suggestions to approach this problem? I am glad for any help. Thank you!

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Well, my question was how to create objects in the given form. Is that to specific? Than I can surely explain the reasons that lead to that question.

Comment: Look more into generics; specifically erasure. What you're trying to do is not possible. When you declare `DollFactory<ExtDoll<ExtDoll<BaseDoll>>>...` after compile it becomes `DollFactory<Object>`. During runtime there is no way for the factory `df` to know the type parameters it was compiled with. There are techniques for getting around this, but what you actually want is most likely something akin to a linked list. This is a classic "x y problem". This question doesn't address your actual problem, but explores a specific solution that is most likely inappropriate for the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will look in to it.

Comment: I think that when you are at a point where you believe this is a solution worth implementing, it's time to stop writing and instead start thinking and drawing on a board

Comment: I stopped and thought about it for a day, looked into some other example code and managed to make a solution that uses internally a linked list. Thank you!